# I want to show my video in full size on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe tag and in which  I want to show video in full size in any screen like youtube but [image]currently, it shows in small size not fit all area.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
           <iframe oncontextmenu="return false" class="video_container" style="width:90%;height:450px;" src="<?php echo $videoDetail[0]['video_links'];?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
         </div>
```

As per image you can see a video not fit in all areas.

Comment: remove class row and check

Comment: @B.K no not change

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, you have to add some bootstrap class depends on your video screen ratio. Please refer bootstrap documentation [Bootstrap 4 Embed Video](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/embed/).

Comment: @AsfanShaikh I add classes but it's not working

Comment: `<div class="mbed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe oncontextmenu="return false" class="video_container embed-responsive-item" style="width:90%;height:450px;" src="<?php echo $videoDetail[0]['video_links'];?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>`

Comment: `embed-responsive` class is not correct. Try this `<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <iframe oncontextmenu="return false" class="video_container embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $videoDetail[0]['video_links'];?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>`